# Is it recommended to clear the query plan cache

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, query-performance

Pretty much as the title describes. I have just checked a SQL Server and noticed there is a lot of query plan bloat that can be fixed by proper parametrisation.

After making the changes to the code, is it recommended that we clear the query plan cache and let it rebuild itself? Or will it clear itself up in time?

**NB:** Out of the top 50 biggest queries, 47 of them were the same but with different parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend against this.  You have done optimization on probably a small subset of queries, and over time you will see the improvement and performance gain.  But if you just do a clean refresh of the query plan cache you will blow all of the execution plans out of there, affecting more than just your optimizations.

I'd be willing to say the immediate performance degradation isn't worth the smaller gain of using your optimized plans right away.  But again, this is another "it depends".

Comment: Not sure if you saw the edit I put on as you were writing but most of the top queries are like `SELECT blah FROM t WHERE param = 1` then `param = 2` and so on... Does that affect your answer? Sorry if it does, you were too quick :P

Comment: Ah, ok.  I see your note now.  What % of the queries in your plan cache have you optimized?  Not by space, but by `usecounts`.

Comment: Probably no more than 15% for this one query. Don't have access to the server at the moment to check

Comment: @StuartBlackler In that case, I would still recommend not to clear the plan cache as a whole.  You can call `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) and specify the plan handle as a parameter.  This will remove a single plan from the cache.  Writing a little clever T-SQL you could loop through all the plans you want to clear to get them out of there.  The benefit of this is you won't affect the other 85% of the plan cache.  Like most things in production, though, if you decide to go that route definitely test it out in an isolated environment.

Comment: If 47/50 queries are going to be properly parameterized (OP says code is being fixed), I don't see why you wouldn't flush the plan cache after the code is updated. I'd also update stats if you aren't already doing so regularly.

Comment: @EricHiggins So you're looking at the top 50 plans cached.  What about the other 1000 plans that are cached, not changed, and benefiting requests without having to recompile?

Comment: A fair point, though I think it would take more time to fish out the plans you want to cure that it would just to flush. I've never seen it take more than minutes to rebuild a plan cache even on large (data & volume) prod hosts.

Comment: @EricHiggins I'd rather spend 5 minutes writing a quick script (joining plans with sql text to find referencing plans of the newly-optimized query, pretty simple) than spending 1 hour fielding phone calls and explaining to non-data professionals and "curious" (read: "upset") users wondering why there was a performance degradation.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion guys. It's been most helpful :)